# Object graph or individual properties as method parameters?

Tags: design-patterns

Say I have a quite deep object graph, as a simplified example, something like this

```
class Car {
    Engine Engine { get; set; }
    Dashboard Dashboard { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<Wheel> Wheels { get; set; }
}

class Engine {
    Pump FuelPump { get; set; }
    Motor StarterMotor { get; set; }
}
```

And for the sake of the example, instead of Car having a Start() method, I want to have a CarStarter that is in charge of doing this. Imaginine that Car can be a big, deeply nested object graph and the CarStarter only needs access to a couple of properties, some of which are several levels deep. Should I pass the Car object to the CarStarter, or only the properties that are important? So which of these overloads in my simplified example?

```
class CarStarter {
    void Start(Car car) {
        car.Dashboard.Lights.SwitchOn();
        car.Engine.FuelPump.Run();
        car.Engine.StarterMotor.Start();
    }

    void Start(Dashboard dashboard, Pump fuelPump, Motor starterMotor) {
        dashboard.Lights.SwitchOn();
        fuelPump.Run();
        starterMotor.Start();
    }
}
```

The former feels wrong as it requires the CarStarter to have in depth knowledge about the structure of the entire nested structure of the Car class and its properties. It's also slightly opaque as to which properties of the Car object need to be populated when passed to CarStarter in a unit test.

The latter seems the better option to me, but at a risk of ending up with too many parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key phrase I was missing was [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). I was pretty sure that the issue fell under the general auspices of an [Inappropriate Intimacy](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/inappropriate-intimacy) code smell, but the exact "rule" being violated appears to be the Law of Demeter, or Principle of Least Knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

We can create a parameter object as detailed here: http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-parameter-object

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's an interesting way of looking at it. I'm almost coming from the opposite direction - in this case, the parameter list isn't too long; it's too short. We're passing one object which has access to everything else already, but this relies on each method that uses this approach having an in depth knowledge of the structure of this "parameter object".